# C# stops working when performing async post request

Tags: c#, .net, http, asynchronous

I am working on a mobile app, and the problem is that when I perform a async request ( PostAsync ) using Net.Http my program stops running.

Here is my request class, where I perform the requests using Net.Http.

```
...

namespace BSoft.Requests
{
   public class Requests
    {
      public Requests(){}

       public static string HostName =  "https://dev5.360businesssoft.com/";

    private static readonly HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

    public static async Task<string> PerformPostRequest(Dictionary<string, string> values, string path)
    {
        string url = HostName + path;
        FormUrlEncodedContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, content);
        string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return responseString;
    }

}
}
```

and here is my login class, where I call call the request and display the result as string.

```
... 

namespace BSoft.Login
{
public class Login
{
    public Login()
    {
    }      

    public static void PerformLogin(string username, string password, bool remember)
    {
        var values = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        values.Add("User", username);
        values.Add("Password", password);

        var ReturnedObj = Requests.Requests.PerformPostRequest(values, "test.php").Result;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ReturnedObj);
    }
}
}
```

[This is a screenshot of the app, you can notice that the button is freezed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wevVs.png)

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38587852/implementing-function-using-async-version-with-result

Comment: If you can't make your code base async friendly then use a synchronous API like HttpWebRequest instead of HttpClient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The call to `Result` is blocking the gui thread. Instead, `await` the result:

```
var ReturnedObj = await Requests.Requests.PerformPostRequest(values, "test.php");
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ReturnedObj);
```

Your call to `Result` will block the gui thread until `PerformPostRequest` completes, so there's not really a lot of point using the `async` features here. If you really don't want the code to execute asynchronously then you might as well remove the calls to the async methods and make the calls synchronous.

Comment: Better warn that the signature should change to `async Task`

Comment: Jorge Aguiar already answered this, but is there a way to fix it without using async in my PerformLogin function?

Comment: @DariusBuhai - Since your code is really running asynchronously you could always just call the synchronous methods and have your gui thread block which the calls are happening. This is basically what you've got anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
string returnedString = await Requests.Requests.PerformPostRequest(values, "test.php");
```

Comment: This could work, but I don't want to use async for my PerformLogin function

Comment: Is there another way I could do this than using async in every function?

Comment: Not really. `async/await` is "turtles all the way down" usually.